# Disk Array Presents Ghost Drives to OS Given Proper SAS?

Tags: hard-drive, direct-attached-storage

I've recently acquired a disk array that has the strange property of not appearing properly to the operating system (Linux).

The drives in it are 300G each, but appear to the OS as 256K instead (using lsblk)(these are the only disks aside for a few 3.6T drives and an NVME and USB). Usually this means a bad SAS connection (seeing ghost drives). I cannot see how this is the case though, as I have tried using a single SAS cable in all the ports with the same result. The SAS controller is not malfunctioning, and can see other disk arrays perfectly.

I then tried using 2 SAS cables in all combinations of the 8 ports with the same result.

Am I doing something wrong? Why won't this disk array appear to the OS properly?

**Before:**
[image]
**After:**
[image]
****Test Pictures** (Brute force all combinations of 2 SAS cables, checking lsblk with each new config)(obviously for isolation purposes, the expansion SAS was never used):**
[image]
[image]

Front display LEDs are "Blue" whereas the other model disk array (green) uses a "Green Only" status indicator and appears properly.
Blue LEDs on Disk Array that appears strangely (yes, the top 2 disk arrays do have drives in them):
[image]

Back end of disk array "ports":
[image]
[image]

Testing Computer:

```
System:
  Host: DSF Kernel: 5.10.36-2-MANJARO x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc 
  v: 10.2.0 Console: tty pts/4 Distro: Manjaro Linux base: Arch Linux 
Machine:
  Type: Server System: Dell product: PowerEdge R7425 v: N/A 
  serial: <superuser required> 
  Mobo: Dell model: 02MJ3T v: X30 serial: <superuser required> UEFI: Dell 
  v: 1.15.0 date: 09/11/2020 
CPU:
  Info: 2x 32-Core (4-Die) model: AMD EPYC 7601 bits: 64 type: MT MCP MCM SMP 
  arch: Zen rev: 2 cache: L2: 32 MiB 
  flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm 
  bogomips: 562226 
  Speed: 2671 MHz min/max: 1200/2200 MHz boost: enabled Core speeds (MHz): 
  1: 2672 2: 2689 3: 2692 4: 2606 5: 2414 6: 2675 7: 2676 8: 2671 9: 2670 
  10: 2675 11: 2644 12: 2680 13: 2673 14: 2682 15: 2614 16: 2667 17: 2693 
  18: 2661 19: 2689 20: 2687 21: 2594 22: 2529 23: 2694 24: 2687 25: 2681 
  26: 2689 27: 2691 28: 2693 29: 2658 30: 2691 31: 1540 32: 2675 33: 2693 
  34: 2688 35: 2666 36: 2679 37: 2689 38: 2657 39: 2645 40: 2675 41: 2688 
  42: 2612 43: 2688 44: 2666 45: 2690 46: 2693 47: 2682 48: 2689 49: 2683 
  50: 2665 51: 2693 52: 2508 53: 2686 54: 2694 55: 2663 56: 2648 57: 2691 
  58: 2683 59: 2592 60: 2484 61: 2671 62: 2694 63: 2600 64: 2666 65: 2675 
  66: 2694 67: 2647 68: 2685 69: 2670 70: 2682 71: 2438 72: 2687 73: 2662 
  74: 2674 75: 2689 76: 2686 77: 2591 78: 2693 79: 2694 80: 2686 81: 2687 
  82: 2710 83: 2694 84: 2660 85: 2656 86: 2691 87: 1598 88: 2689 89: 2692 
  90: 2673 91: 2749 92: 2684 93: 2655 94: 2578 95: 2796 96: 2721 97: 2652 
  98: 2694 99: 2689 100: 2691 101: 2694 102: 2682 103: 2682 104: 2679 105: 2610 
  106: 2683 107: 2690 108: 2685 109: 2657 110: 2690 111: 2680 112: 2644 
  113: 2690 114: 2667 115: 2693 116: 2687 117: 2684 118: 2693 119: 2689 
  120: 2683 121: 2679 122: 2664 123: 2693 124: 2694 125: 2663 126: 2681 
  127: 2692 128: 2679 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Matrox Systems Integrated Matrox G200eW3 Graphics driver: mgag200 
  v: kernel bus-ID: 03:00.0 
  Display: server: X.org 1.20.11 driver: loaded: modesetting tty: 84x27 
  Message: Advanced graphics data unavailable in console. Try -G --display 
Audio:
  Message: No device data found. 
  Sound Server-1: JACK v: 0.125.0 running: no 
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 14.2 running: yes 
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.28 running: no 
Network:
  Device-1: Intel I350 Gigabit Network vendor: Dell 4P I350-t rNDC driver: igb 
  v: kernel port: N/A bus-ID: 01:00.0 
  IF: eno1 state: down mac: b8:ca:3a:64:a4:b8 
  Device-2: Intel I350 Gigabit Network vendor: Dell 4P I350-t rNDC driver: igb 
  v: kernel port: N/A bus-ID: 01:00.1 
  IF: eno2 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: b8:ca:3a:64:a4:b9 
  Device-3: Intel I350 Gigabit Network vendor: Dell 4P I350-t rNDC driver: igb 
  v: kernel port: N/A bus-ID: 01:00.2 
  IF: eno3 state: down mac: b8:ca:3a:64:a4:ba 
  Device-4: Intel I350 Gigabit Network vendor: Dell 4P I350-t rNDC driver: igb 
  v: kernel port: N/A bus-ID: 01:00.3 
  IF: eno4 state: down mac: b8:ca:3a:64:a4:bb 
  Device-5: Intel 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network driver: ixgbe v: kernel 
  port: 4020 bus-ID: 41:00.0 
  IF: enp65s0f0 state: down mac: 80:61:5f:0a:35:66 
  Device-6: Intel 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network driver: ixgbe v: kernel 
  port: 4000 bus-ID: 41:00.1 
  IF: enp65s0f1 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 80:61:5f:0a:35:67 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 512 GiB used: 8.55 GiB (1.7%) fs: btrfs dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2 
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 511 MiB used: 576 KiB (0.1%) fs: vfat 
  dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1 
  ID-3: /home size: 512 GiB used: 8.55 GiB (1.7%) fs: btrfs dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2 
  ID-4: /var/log size: 512 GiB used: 8.55 GiB (1.7%) fs: btrfs 
  dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2 
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 419.01 GiB used: 2.09 GiB (0.5%) 
  dev: /dev/nvme0n1p3 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 46.2 C mobo: 0 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:
  Processes: 2521 Uptime: 8h 41m Memory: 503.63 GiB used: 150.13 GiB (29.8%) 
  Init: systemd Compilers: gcc: 10.2.0 Packages: 1221 Shell: Bash v: 5.1.8 
  inxi: 3.3.04
```

Is there something I'm missing? How can I get this disk array to appear properly?

**EDIT 0:** The model of the controller (I have no other information as there isn't any stickers on the disk array) is similar to [this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/265030049018?chn=ps&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=711-117182-37290-0&mkcid=2&itemid=265030049018&targetid=1263433205934&device=m&mktype=pla&googleloc=9004572&poi=&campaignid=10459842381&mkgroupid=122657840056&rlsatarget=aud-622027676548:pla-1263433205934&abcId=2146002&merchantid=101988578)

**EDIT 1: **
The leading hypothesis is a prior configuration. Does anyone know how to set the configuration to a direct attached storage option?

Comment: It's a pretty safe bet you'll need to connect it to a network and look at the configuration of the array via a CLI or some sort of web GUI.  Assuming this is a second hand array, it's likely the prior configuration wasn't completely wiped and the controller is still managing the the drives.

Comment: Is there any standard way to do this for this Netapp controller? Like a default IP or something? I'll look for it using `sudo ss` or `netstat`

Comment: Sorry, I have no direct experience with NetApp - you might want to update the original post with the fact it's a NetApp array and model.

Comment: Sorry, one second, where does the NetApp bit of this come in? Are you trying to connect NetApp shelves to a regular PC-based server, or the opposite, or something else?

Comment: I'm just trying to get the drives to apper as a DAS. Disk array -> Poweredge Server. I'm not looking to do anything complicated at this point. Let's just keep it local for now :D

Comment: I just don't know where NetApp comes into this, you mention a NetApp controller you see.